# How can i specify to start reading past a specifc number of words from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to read specifically past a certain number of words from a file.
I wrote this but it seems i am not doing it properly! I am curios to know if there is a better way of doing it .
This is my code:

```
FILE* filePointer;
wstring inputString = L"";
wstring wstr = L"";

int position = 0;

_wfopen_s(&filePointer, fileToReadFrom, L"r");
_setmode(_fileno(filePointer), _O_U8TEXT);

wifstream file(filePointer);

getline(file, inputString);
while (inputString[position] != L' ')
{
    position++;
}
fseek(filePointer, position, SEEK_SET);//start reading after first word

while (file.good())
{
     getline(file, inputString);

     for (wsregex_iterator it(inputString.begin(), inputString.end(), biRegx), it_end; it != it_end; ++it)
     {
         //Filling the bigram container
         wstr = (wstring) (*it)[0];
         bigramStatMap[wstr]++;

     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a for loop, reading the number of words that you need:

```
unsigned int words_before_begin;
std::string sux_string;
std::ifstream file_stream("Your file");

for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < words_before_begin ; ++i)
    file_stream >> aux_string; //istream reads strings word by word, using spaces as separators.

/* Your reading code starts here */
```

Comment: and after that filestream would point past those words? and calling getline() afterwards would get the line past those words?

Comment: @Hossein Yes. What this code does is reading the first n words of the file. If you read n words, you will point at the n+1 word (Supossing that you file only has words).

Answer (score 1):

Copy whole vector

```
std::ifstream stream ("file_name");

std::vector<std::string> words;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream),
                  std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                  std::back_inserter(words)
                 );
```

Start Accessing from `words[position+1]`